# How to write formula based on pick-list value of the pick-list field

Tags: formula, formula-field, fields, configuration

I would like to write a formula to count the number of days based on the conditions mentioned below..

If the Status__c (Picklist field) = Draft, calculate based on Now() - Last modifed date.

If the Satus__c is another pick-list value other than draft, calculate based on Created date - Lastmodified date

Answer (score 2):

Something like this will work

```
IF(
     ISPICKVAL(Status__c, 'Draft'),
     NOW() - LastModifiedDate,
     CreatedDate - LastModifiedDate
)
```

For more info on Formulas and Operators check some of these out

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions.htm&language=en_US

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Formulas

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/usefulFormulaFields/

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=tips_on_building_formulas.htm&language=en_US

Comment: HI Ninja,Thanks for your answer it works..One more question the number of days difference wasn't included with todays date. How do we manipulate this formula to include todays date in that calculation

Comment: I dont understand.  NOW() is the current time, current date.

Comment: With this formula, it was calculating in this way..Ex: Now (08/12) - Created date (08/08) = 4. But, I want to include the today's date so that it will give 5 days instead of 4.Let me know how to achieve it

Comment: What time Zone are you in?  Formulas will use GMT time so this could be the issue.

Comment: I am in PST (pacific Std time)

Comment: Add 1 to the result of the formula?
IF(
     ISPICKVAL(Status__c, 'Draft'),
     (NOW() - LastModifiedDate)+1,
     CreatedDate - LastModifiedDate
)